# Where am i going wrong with this calculated formula (ISBLANK)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

So on my calculated formula in share point, I can get it to do what I want it to do with the following formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF([Start of Absence],NOW(),"d")<28,"No","Yes")
```

However it shows yes for dates with no date in it, this does make sense, however I want it to be a "NO" if no date is entered yet, I have tried the following but keep getting errors:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start of Absence]),"No", DATEDIF([Start of Absence],NOW(),"d")<28,"No","Yes"))
```

I know I am missing something and want to learn, but what is it :).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing an extra IF. Try this:

```
=IF(IsBlank([Start of Absence]),"No",IF(DATEDIF([Start of Absence],NOW(),"d")<28,"No","Yes"))
```

Comment: thank you, you are amazing and can now see the logic, for future ones i do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OR** function inside IF function like this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Start of Absence]),DATEDIF([Start of Absence],NOW(),"d")<28) ,"No","Yes"))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))